Does the earth get destroyed after day of brahma as it is approx the age of our earth and sun which is 4.32 billion years
As the day of brahma is 4.32 billion years which is approx the age of our earth and sun and also if we are in 28 mahayuga's-kaliyuga of 7th manvantar of the  51st year of the brahma who's age is 100 years which is 311 trillion years then this means that all the other days of brahma that had passed must happened in another earth somewhere in our universe.

Bhagavān Krishna's death marked the end of Dvapara Yuga(द्वापर युग) and the start of Kali Yuga (कलि युग), which is dated to 17/18 February 3102 BCE. Lasting for 432,000 years (1,200 divine years/देव वर्ष), Kali Yuga began 5,125 years ago and has 426,875 years left as of 2024 CE. Kali Yuga will end in the year 428,899 CE.
According to the Hindu Scriptures, Kalki Avatara (कल्कि अवतार/கல்கி அவதாரம்) will be appeared at the end of the Kali Yuga corroborated by Srimad Bhagavatam [12.2.23] as given below:
 यदावतीर्णो भगवान् कल्किर्धर्मपतिर्हरि: । कृतं भविष्यति तदा प्रजासूतिश्च सात्त्विकी ॥ २३ ॥    
 yadāvatīrṇo bhagavān kalkir dharma-patir hariḥ kṛtaṁ bhaviṣyati tadā prajā-sūtiś ca sāttvikī ॥ 23 ॥
 
 When the Supreme Lord has appeared on earth as Kalki, the maintainer of religion, 
 Satya-yuga will begin, and human society will bring forth progeny in the mode of goodness.

 -Srimad Bhagavatam: 12.2.23

So, Kalki Avtara will come on earth to eliminate the evils from Kali Yuga and for the revival of Satya Yuga. However, another opinion is that the tenth avatar of Vishnu is seen as the form before Pralaya (प्रलय/Dissolution of Universe/பிரளயம்).
The scriptures propound the cyclic theory of creation. The cycle of Sṛṣṭi, Sthiti and Laya goes on endlessly. The dissolution, called laya or pralaya, is of four types [Srimad Bhagavatam: 12.2.38]:

Nitya (नित्य) - Nitya pralaya refers to Jīvātman (जीवात्मन्) being born in the different forms of animals, reptiles, birds and so on and then again he dies and thus rotates in the cycle of births and deaths again and again [Garuda Puranam: 2.9.25.17].
Naimittika (नैमित्तिक) - Naimittika pralaya is the dissolution that takes place at the end of a day of Brahmā, called kalpa which is equivalent to 4.32 billion human years [Srimad Bhagavatam: 12.4.4].
Prākṛtika (प्राकृतिक)- The prākṛtika pralaya is the dissolution of everything into prakṛti at the end of Brahmā’s life of hundred years equivalent to 311.04 trillion human years [Srimad Bhagavatam: 12.4.22].
Ātyantika (आत्यन्तिक)- When Māyā, Puruṣa and Kāla get merged in the imperishable refulgence by the Lord’s will, then the Lord alone exists (without a second). That Pralaya is called Ātyantika (Final or Absolute) [Garuda Puranam: 2.9.25.59].

Nevertheless, just to have a feel of the mind-boggling measure of time in Hinduism, let us see them all below.

What is 1 human year? This is also known as sāvana year. It is 360 days. 1 day = 24 hours.What is 1 divine year? It is also known as Deva Varusha (देव वर्ष). It is 360 sāvana years.
What is 1 yuga cycle? It is known as chatur yuga which consists of Satya (or Krita), Treta, Dvapara and Kali yugas. Total duration of yuga cycle is 12,000 divine years = 4,320,000 sāvana years. 1 yuga cycle is known as Mahāyuga (महायुग).
What is 1 Manvantra? it is 71 yuga cycles which is 852,000 divine years = 306,720,000 sāvana years [Vishnu Smriti 20.11].
What is kalpa? It is known as Brahma’s day (12-hour day proper). It consists of 14 Manvantras. This is 4.32 billion sāvana years [Vishnu Smriti 20.13]. This is equivalent to a thousand Caturyugas  [Vishnu Smriti 20.12].
What is day and night of brahma? A kalpa is followed by a pralaya (dissolution) of equal length, which together constitute a day and night of Brahma. This is 4.32 + 4.32 = 8.64 billion sāvana years [Srimad Bhagavatam: 12.4.2-3].
What is 1 year of brahma? 360 kalpa + 360 pralaya.
What is Mahākalpa ? It is also known as life-span of Brahma which is 100 years. It is 36,000 kalpa + 36,000 pralaya which is 311.04 trillion sāvana years [Vishnu Smriti 20.15].
What is a day of Purusha? Age of one brahman (life-span of brahman) is a day of Purusha (Vishnu) [Vishnu Smriti 20.16].

The present age of of cosmos according to vedic system is as follows:
There are 14 Manvantras in a kalpa (Brahma’s day). The present period is passing through the seventh Manvantra called Vaivasvata Manvantara (वैवस्वत मन्वन्तर).
One Manvantara consists of 71 Mahayugas, out of which 27 Mahayugas have already elapsed. Now we are in 28th Mahayuga and after passing of Satya, Treta and Dwapara Yugas, we have already entered into Kali Yuga. Thus, at end of present Kali Yuga, Satya Yuga (aka Krita Yuga) of the next 29th Mahayuga will begin.
Conclusion:
I) Your first question Does the earth gets destroyed after day of brahma as it is approx the age of our earth and sun which is 4.32 billion years?
1) The answer to your question lies in the 4th sloka of Srimad Bhagavatam [12.4].
 एष नैमित्तिक: प्रोक्त: प्रलयो यत्र विश्वसृक् । शेतेऽनन्तासनो विश्वमात्मसात्कृत्य चात्मभू: ॥ ४ ॥
 eṣa naimittikaḥ proktaḥ pralayo yatra viśva-sṛk śete ’nantāsano viśvam ātmasāt-kṛtya cātma-bhūḥ

 This is called the naimittika [नैमित्तिक], or occasional, annihilation, 
 during which the original creator, Lord Nārāyaṇa, lies down upon the bed of 
 Ananta Śeṣa and absorbs the entire universe within Himself 
 while Lord Brahmā sleeps.॥ 4 ॥

 Srimad Bhagavatam: 12.4.4     

Naimittika pralaya (नैमित्तिक प्रलय) is the dissolution that takes place at the end of a day of Brahmā, called kalpa which is equivalent to 4.32 billion sāvana (human) years [Srimad Bhagavatam: 12.4.4].
2) Vāsudeva-māhātmya of Skanda purana [2.9.25.19] says:
The Destruction that is occasioned by the Night of 
the Creator of the universe [Brahmā] is called the Naimittika [periodic]
Dissolution or Destruction. It occurs on everyday [of God Brahmā].

 -Skanda purana: 2.9.25.19

Skanda purana is in corroboration with Srimad Bhagavatam.
3) In Garuda Puranam [Danvantri Samhita, Ch-224], Rishi Sūta says:

After the expiry of a thousand of such chatur Yugas (a kapla), occurs
the Naimittika dissolution (causal or periodical) of the universe.
At the close of each Kalpa will follow a rainless period of a hundred
years, during which the seven suns will rise in the sky, which, by
absorbing all water, will burn down the three regions with a dreadful
conflagration of fire. ॥ 1-2 ॥
Inmates of the regions of Bhu, Bhuba (Bhuva?),
Sva and Maha, will fly to the region of Jana, and the god Vishnu,
manifest in the shape of Rudra, shall consume the Nether regions
(Patalas. Clouds of all shades of colour will originate from the mouth
of this Rudra-form Vishnu, which will incessantly pour down torrents
of rain, for a hundred years.॥ 3-4 ॥
From the mouth of Vishnu winds,abnormally augmented and enraged, shall
blow in storms for a hundred years.  On the annihilation of all
creatures, both mobile and immobile, the god Vishnu, assuming the
shape of Brahma, shall lie down on the one universal ocean of
undivided waters.॥ 5 ॥
Thus sleeping for another hundred years, the god, Visnu, will again, create the universe. Now hear me, O Saunaka, describe the Natural dissolution of the universe (Annihilation of Nature).॥ 6 ॥
-Garuda Puranam: Danvantri Samhita, Ch-224.

Garuda Puranam too is in corroboration with Srimad Bhagavatam and Skanda purana but narrates Naimittika pralaya in detail.
II) Your second and final question days of brahma that had passed must happened in another earth somewhere in our universe
Unless there is enough pramāna (proof) for such existence of a parallel earth, your claim can't be acceptable.
Good Luck!

thanks for answering
